# Is "Naruto Box Set 2" (or "3") equal to Naruto Shippuden anime?

Tags: naruto

I just started watching *Naruto* anime and wanted to start getting into manga instead. I want to start reading from where *Naruto Shippuden* starts in the anime. I am new to anime and manga, so I don't know much about them.

I heard that it starts from 28, but is it until 72, or would that be another part of anime?

Answer (score 1):

No. Naruto Shippuden is a new series, taking place after the conclusion of the original Naruto series, with older characters and some new ones.